# input to reshape is different from ideal[input to reshape is a tensor with x value,but requested y value]

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, tfrecord

I am trying to use a bunch of 720*480, images to train my model.This error is at the preprocessing of images as in the upper part of TrainModelscript. [eg of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INNM5.jpg)

So the part went wrong should be this part: IF I am not wrong.ahahah.
batch_features, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()

But further investigation shows that the error is kinda not at that line? as print(), doesn't have output.
I had no idea how to debug this. As I am new to ML, and dealing with cv to arrays or tuples.

Thus,goes back to my tfrecord.

```
createTFrecordscript:

import tensorflow as tf
import os ,glob
import argparse
import random


os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
#func for 2feature
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
#func for create a tf example with 2 feature
def _create_tfexample(image_data, label):
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'image': _bytes_feature(image_data),
            'label': _int64_feature(label)
            }))
    return example

#not sure,create a id for each file?
def enumerate_filestoId(file_list, sort=True):
    file_ids = {}
    file_id_counter = 0

    if sort:
        file_list.sort()

    for file_name in file_list:
        if file_name not in file_ids:
            file_ids[class_name] = file_id_counter
            file_id_counter += 1

    return file_ids

#main func
def create_tfrecords(save_dir, dataset_name, filenames, class_ids, num_shards):

    im_per_shard = int( len(filenames) / num_shards ) + 1

    for shard in range(num_shards):
        output_filename = os.path.join(save_dir, '{}_{:03d}-of-{:03d}.tfrecord'
                                       .format(dataset_name, shard, num_shards))
        print('Writing into {}'.format(output_filename))
        filenames_shard = filenames[shard*im_per_shard:(shard+1)*im_per_shard]

        with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(output_filename) as tfrecord_writer:

            for filename in filenames_shard:
                image =  tf.gfile.GFile(filename, 'rb').read()
                class_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filename))
                label = class_ids[class_name]

                example = _create_tfexample(image, label)
                tfrecord_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    print('Finished writing {} images into TFRecords'.format(len(filenames)))

"""
def _is_png(filenames):
  Determine if a file is or is not PNG format image.
  Args:
    filename: string, path of the image file.
  Returns:
    boolean indicating if the image is a PNG.

  return '.png' in filenames
"""

def main(args):
    #find filenameadd it to a list
    supported_formats = ['*.jpg', '*.JPG', '*.jpeg', '*.JPEG']
    filenames = []
    for extension in supported_formats:
        pattern = os.path.join(args.input_dir, '**', extension)
        filenames.extend(glob.glob(pattern, recursive=False))
    #for random them?
    random.seed(args.seed)
    random.shuffle(filenames)

    num_test = int(args.split_ratio * len(filenames))
    num_shards_test = int(args.split_ratio * args.num_shards)
    num_shards_train = args.num_shards - num_shards_test

    # write the list of classes and their corresponding ids to a file
    file_list = [name for name in os.listdir(args.input_dir)
                    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(args.input_dir, name))]
    file_ids = enumerate_filestoId(file_list)
    with open(os.path.join(args.output_dir, 'classes.txt'), 'w') as f:
        for cid in file_ids:
            print('{}:{}'.format(file_ids[cid], cid), file=f)

    # create TFRecords for the training and test sets
    create_tfrecords(save_dir=args.output_dir,
                     dataset_name='train',
                     filenames=filenames[num_test:],
                     file_ids=file_ids,
                     num_shards=num_shards_train)
    create_tfrecords(save_dir=args.output_dir,
                     dataset_name='test',
                     filenames=filenames[:num_test],
                     file_ids=file_ids,
                     num_shards=num_shards_test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input_dir', type=str,
                        help='path to the directory where the images will be read from')
    parser.add_argument('--output_dir', type=str,
                        help='path to the directory where the TFRecords will be saved to')
    parser.add_argument('--num_shards', type=int,
                        help='total number of shards')
    parser.add_argument('--split_ratio', type=float, default=0.2,
                        help='ratio of number of images in the test set to the total number of images')
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=42,
                        help='random seed for repeatable train/test splits')
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    main(args)
```

error:

```
2019-11-30 11:41:22.526045: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at iterator_ops.cc:929 : Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_Dataset_map_parse_function_29}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 97934 values, but the requested shape has 1036800
         [[{{node Reshape}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TrainEvalSaveModel2.py", line 134, in <module>
    batch_features, batch_labels,Runcounter=imgs_input_fn(tfRecordspath, perform_shuffle=False, repeat_count=1,batch_size=4,Runcounter=0)
  File "TrainEvalSaveModel2.py", line 51, in imgs_input_fn
    batch_features, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()#disabled for image direct to tensor
  File "E:\Coding\PYFastCache\PYVenv\Venv37_gpuacc\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 737, in get_next
    return self._next_internal()
  File "E:\Coding\PYFastCache\PYVenv\Venv37_gpuacc\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 651, in _next_internal
    output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
  File "E:\Coding\PYFastCache\PYVenv\Venv37_gpuacc\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2691, in iterator_get_next_sync
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_Dataset_map_parse_function_29}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 97934 values, but the requested shape has 1036800
         [[{{node Reshape}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```

TrainModelscript:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import cProfile
import os

Runcounter=0
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()


def imgs_input_fn(tfRecordspath, perform_shuffle=False, repeat_count=1, batch_size=4,Runcounter=0):
    def parse_function(serialized):
        features = {
            'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
        # Parse the serialized data so we get a dict with our data.
        parsed_example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized,features)
        Image_ypix=720
        Image_xpix=480
        input_name="Kakoii"
        # Get the image as raw bytes.
        image_shape = tf.stack([Image_ypix,Image_xpix, 3]) #,if not flatten,on this
        image_raw = parsed_example['image']
        label = tf.cast(parsed_example['label'], tf.float32)
        # Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.
        image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.uint8)
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
        image = tf.reshape(image,image_shape)
        #image = tf.reshape(image,-1),flatten
        #image = tf.subtract(image, pixel_val?) # Zero-center by mean pixel,too complex
        image = tf.reverse(image, axis=[2]) # 'RGB'->'BGR'
        #Yourimage = tf.reverse(image, axis=[2]) # 'RGB'->'BGR'
        tensor = dict(zip([input_name], [image])), [label] #onlycomplicate it
        #print(image)
        #print(tensor),debug use
        #tensor=Yourimage
        return tensor
    mydataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfRecordspath)
    # Parse the serialized data in the TFRecords files.
    # This returns TensorFlow tensors for the image and labels.
    tensor = mydataset.map(parse_function)
    if perform_shuffle:
        # Randomizes input using a window of 256 elements (read into memory)
        tensor = tensor.shuffle(buffer_size=480)
    tensor = tensor.repeat(repeat_count)  # Repeats dataset this # times
    tensor = tensor.batch(batch_size)  # Batch size to use
    iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(tensor)
    #batch_features=iterator # directly image to tensor only
    #batch_labels=iterator #for image to tensor only
    batch_features, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()#disabled for image direct to tensor
    #Runcounter=1,removed sys
    #print(batch_features)
    #print(batch_labels)
    return batch_features, batch_labels,Runcounter

def Proceedprocess(tfRecordspath,batch_features, batch_labels):
#usesruncounter to check,removed
    exein=input("continue?(exit,savemodel,yes):")
    if exein=="yes":
        NNTrainEvalBuild(tfRecordspath,batch_features, batch_labels)
    elif exein=="exit":
        sys.exit()
    elif exein=="savemodel":
        savemodel()
    else:
        print("assume can proceed trainmodel")
        NNTrainEvalBuild(tfRecordspath,batch_features, batch_labels)


#a old low level api func in broken save file,removed 


def convertTuple(yourtup): 
    finalstr =  ''.join(yourtup) 
    return finalstr



def NNTrainEvalBuild(tfRecordspath,batch_features, batch_labels):
    print("start model&preprocess")
    batch_size=8
    N_EPOCHS=8
    N_TRAIN=8
    N_VALIDATION=16

    convertTuple(batch_features)# direct image to tensoroff
    convertTuple(batch_labels)

    """somee old code only in broken code file"""

    inputs1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,),tensor=(batch_features,batch_labels))
    out1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs1)
    in2= tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(out1)
    out2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(in2)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs1, outputs=out2)

    #with planned,create it
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

    #statrt train
    tf.keras.Model.fit(train_iterator,
    epochs=N_EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=N_TRAIN // batch_size,
    validation_data=val_iterator,
    validation_steps=N_VALIDATION // batch_size)
    print("finish training")

def savemodel():
    #createmodel
    savemodelpath=input("Save Model's path:")
    tf.keras.models.save_model(savemodelpath,save_format="tf")


tfRecordspath=input("TFRecords's path:")
batch_features, batch_labels,Runcounter=imgs_input_fn(tfRecordspath, perform_shuffle=False, repeat_count=1,batch_size=4,Runcounter=0)

Proceedprocess(tfRecordspath,batch_features, batch_labels)
```

Comment: check your image dimensions , e.g. after this "image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.uint8)" and make sure its really 720x480.  I blv you can call image.shape to see this.

Comment: oh god,it shows: (?,)

Comment: i added as you said: print(image.shape); output:(?,)

Comment: Thank you,so now we know that the image is definitely gone wrong during preprocessing or in tfrecords. Then I should probably go study cv and related functions.^^

Comment: I'm not sure, iirc tensorflow has a 'placeholder' concept where variables (and their sizes) can be indeterminate until runtime

Comment: Not quite sure, about the runtime you are referring to.Isn't executing the script itself already in runtime. Or maybe you are referring to the moment the computer load each image from the tfrecords? with that we had once hit a dead end,Convert raw byte strings into tensors.

Comment: Convert raw byte strings into tensors.<This will probably have a linear output >(?,). BTW,Is (?,) considered linear?Then maybe should I implement something like (show image with opencv..hm.ok,Just do it.will report to you.

Comment: ok even the(image_raw)=(),so something add definetely gone wrong.It cannot be read by opencv either.So i think it went become a data that is not a picture itself during the parsing. Is it supposed to be like that? ^^

Comment: are you seeing any output from the line " print('{}:{}'.format(file_ids[cid], cid), file=f)" ?  That should tell you whether your path to images is ok

Comment: I am very sorry, I cannot understand the variable used in the code you given to me. What is the variable(file_ids) suppose to be in my case?As I only have a tfrecord file,which is kinda like a zipfile.Only at runtime, will the zipped file be opened and turn into a set of images. ^^

Comment: I blv. the file_ids should be a bunch of numbers.  If you don't get any output that could point to a path problem.

Comment: by path you mean the path to the tfrecords?